# How to update after every thirty days

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this code in my controller that describes a favourite subscription:

```
def favourite_subscribe
    if  FavouriteSubscription.favourite_subscription_check_cost(current_user, @user)
      @favourite_subscription = FavouriteSubscription.add_favourite_subscription(current_user, @user)
      @user.favourite_subscriber_total = @user.favourite_subscriber_total + 1 
      @user.save
      redirect_to :back, :notice => "Congratulations, you are now a subscriber!"
```

Now what I want to do is be able to update the favorite subscription every thirty days. This is to act as a subscription model (people pay for subscription). The only problem Is I have no idea on how to repeate this every thirty days. If anybody has any Ideas that will be great : )

Edit: Can I react to a controller with rake task.  If I can then how

Comment: Any sort of cron job or gem equivalent.

Comment: whenever gem to execute it as a corn https://github.com/javan/whenever

Comment: I have whenever job installed but a lot of what I need has to be part of the controller and as far as I know you can't point whenever job to your controller (unless I am totally wrong).

Comment: this codes should be in a model for good code practice

Comment: This code belongs to model

Comment: And model methods you can call from your cron jobs too.

Comment: I tried writting it as a model. The problem is that the controller depends on the controller of a user. (gives me undefined @user)

Comment: Is there a way to write this for a model?

Comment: You cannot just move the code to the model, simply retrieve the user from the subscription, rather than @user from current_user.

Comment: Im not really a programmer (hired a freelancer to do almost all the work). So I don't want to do too much and mess everything up. Is there no way to just do this in the controller or through a view?

Comment: Or is there a different cron job gem that can redo the code every thirty days

Comment: Can I call the controller in a rake task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the [delayed_job_recurring](https://github.com/amitree/delayed_job_recurring) gem for scheduling recurring tasks. I have been very happy with it, and feel it is pretty straightforward to setup.
Happy to help if you decide to give it a try and have any issues setting it up.

Comment: Can i use this to redo the controller like I said above?

Comment: @Jakxna360 You can move the code from your controller to a model, it would work in either place. IMO, this code belongs in a model. Put the code you want to execute every 30 days within the `def perform` method in, say, your `FavoriteSubscription` model, or whatever you decide to call it.

Comment: Thank you... the only problem Is I am not a programmer (I hired a freelancer to write the app). So I have no idea how to put it in the model. This is why I need a way to repeat something in the controller every thirty days. I need to do this the easiest way possible without changing many things (I don't know how to fix it).

Comment: @Jakxna360 Hmmm, well maybe pass the info along to your hired freelancer. If he/she is a programmer, they should know how to get this code to work in either a controller OR a model.

Comment: I'm broke at the moment so I don't have access to him. I need to get this subscription thing up and running but I have no idea how.

Comment: Ended up using delayed_job... works pretty well once you learn how to use it.